# How to create a dynamic table structure in SQL from multiple delimited text files?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv, vba

I have about 100,000+ delimited text files (they dont have same number of columns in each file, e.g. some files have 10 columns, some have 20 and so on). I need to upload all of them to SQL server. Please suggest how can I do it?

I also have an excel spreadsheet enlisting the names/path where files are stored and also the number of columns in each text file. I am clueless how to go about it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In SQL columns require data-types and names.  Do you have anything stored anywhere that tells you what this should be?  I suggest you load all of your files as just one VARCHAR column into a temporary staging table.  Then have some VBA or dynamic SQL that reads the data in that temporary staging table to create some dynamic SQL that will create a real table to copy the data into.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are able to use C# (or other programming language) to create an app which will help you to complete the task. The program should do the following:

1. Run through all the files and determine all the columns you need.
2. Create a table on SQL server with columns the program found. Set datatype `varchar(max)` for each column.
3. Run through all the files again and insert data to the table. There is 2 ways you can go:

   a) Insert data row by row. Pretty slow, but simple.

   b) If you use C# you can implement your own `DataReader` and use `SqlBulkCopy` class to bulk insert data into the table

Here is some link which may help you:

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server

http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2011/12/22/using-a-custom-idatareader-to-stream-data-into-a-database/

http://daniel.wertheim.se/2010/11/10/c-custom-datareader-for-sqlbulkcopy/

Comment: Sorry I can't access anything other than Excel/SQL/VBA. Command prompt is also blocked.

Comment: Probably, you could write it on VBA, but it's pretty hard